# How to Prerender Uno webassembly or make uno webassembly sites load in under 2 seconds?

Tags: blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly, uno

I am strongly considering the uno platform for cross platform app development.

However, the first and most important app is the mobile website. From all my tests, uno's webassembly sites on browsers (eg safari) takes more than 30 seconds before the first content is displayed.

It's slow even with all the various mono runtime execution modes such as Interpreter, InterpreterAndAOT, etc. Even a basic hello world is very slow. This is a major roadblock. ^

I know we can prerender Blazor WebAssembly websites. So I am wondering whether someone can point me in the direction of how to pretender an uno WebAssembly website as well. Perhaps that can solve the load time problem.

Nonetheless, I'm open to other options to improve uno as well. The site load from the users perspective needs to be less than 2 seconds.

Comment: I think you have to use "Blazor Server" instead of "Blazor WebAssembly".

Comment: This is for an uno project which doesn’t have a razor server option for web apps